# How to define API gateway URLs when splitting a monolith into microservices

Tags: microservices, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

We are splitting a monolith application into microservices. This will be a gradual process, it means initially we will start with 2 microservices, later we will split them into more and so on.

The monoligh exposes a REST API which provides methods for managing tens of different entities (e.g. users, user_types, roles, role_types, etc.). There is only one consumer of the REST API exposed by the monolith - a Javascript frontend app.

We are currently investigating two possibilities how to configure the API gateway (Zuul):

1. URLs will contain the microservice name, e.g. `/api/dictionary` will serve `/api/dictionary/user_types` and `/api/dictionary/role_types`, while `/api/data` will serve `/api/data/users` and `/api/data/roles`. It means the URLs will change over time as we create more microservices. Everytime we do it the consumer (frontend) will have to be changed.
2. URLs will be based on the entity names, e.g. `/api/users`, `/api/user_types`, `/api/roles` and `/api/role_types`. The disadvantage is that the Zuul configuration will have to contain an explicit configuration for every single entity managed by the system.

Which of the above approaches is correct?

Comment: I will suggest to go with first approach, as it will give you the ability to easily identify the micro-service from the url itself. Secondly you will have less effort to maintain the service registry for new endpoints. Might be second apprach will help you to have no or very less chnage on the consumer side as they don't have to chnage the URL. But second approach is fine in short-term But on long term the first apprach is better from my point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manmay saying is correct. You should go with first approach for long term gain.
If you still want alternative, then you can combine both of these approach by configuring your API gateway in such a way that,  It will route your request

- /api/users -> /api/data/users
- /api/user_types -> /api/dictionary/user_types
- /api/roles -> /api/data/roles
- /api/role_types -> /api/dictionary/role_types

By this approach, you will not have to compromise any of the concerns like maintenance or client side changes.

Comment: Isn't the alternative you have described the 2nd approach from the question?

Comment: @AdamSiemion 2nd approach that you are saying is different from what  I propsed. In client side you will be using "api/users" url. Configure your gateway in such a way that you client make request to this url then that request will get forwarded to  "/api/data/users" which is nothing but your microservice url. Means you will not have to make any change in client code even if your microservice url gets changed. You just have to update corresponding mapping in gateway.